# Attribute requirements at design time

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

Using some XUnit attributes as an example there is a TheoryAttribute and an InlineDataAttribute.

If I have a test method and I only apply the Theory attribute to it Visual Studio underlines the method name in red and complains that Theory methods must have test data and parameters.

[image]

If I then add an InlineDataAttribute as in the following example:

[image]

Visual Studio complains about no matching parameter for value 12 in this case.

My question is, how can I write my own custom attributes in a way that they can validate what they are being placed on at **design time** just like these XUnit attributes are?

Comment: Most likely XUnit added a code analyzer as well which is a library that hooks into the Roslyn compiler magic to provide code inspections and fixes.

Comment: If that is true then that would make sense as to why I can't find anything on this topic.

Comment: It's xUnit's own custom analysers, see here: https://github.com/xunit/xunit.analyzers

Comment: And the rules they contain: https://xunit.github.io/xunit.analyzers/rules/

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys